Unexpected output from masked area calculation in Google Earth Engine
Using a 500m MODIS burned area dataset in GEE, I want to find the area burned in a period of time (say, a few months). Specifically, I want to find the area of pixels that have burned one or more times during the time period. To get pixels that have been burned at least one time, I summed all the images during the time period (I summed the band 'BurnDate', which has values between 0 and 366, where 0 is not burned) and created a mask from this. Then I calculated area using .pixelArea() and ee.Reducer.sum with this mask. Since the pixels are 500m, it seems like the output value should be a factor of 0.25km, but the output has a very high level of precision (area = 2.5726952031250003). I'd like to figure out why this is, and I'm not sure if I did this calculation correctly.
Is it because the reducer is clipping the result to the geometry, resulting in partial pixels?
Here is my code:
var test_month = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD64A1')
.filterDate("2018-02-01","2018-05-01")
.filterBounds(roi).select('BurnDate');
var total = test_month.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());  // sum all images in time period
//mask out all areas with a sum of 0 (0 means unburned), keep areas with a sum of 1 or more
//output should be a masked layer with burned areas for the whole 3 months, with values representing the sum of the burn days (physically meaningless but will be used for a mask)

var burnAreaMask = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).updateMask(total.gte(1)) // Get total pixel area for the month in square km
var burnArea = burnAreaMask      // Get sum of masked pixel areas over the time period
      .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
        geometry: roi,
        scale: 500,
        crs: 'EPSG:4326',      
        maxPixels: 1e13
      });
      
// Returns a dict with the format: {area:0.0}
var BAvalue = burnArea.get('area'); // get value associated with dict key

var f = ee.Feature(null, {  //originally ee.Feature(null, {})
      'burned_area_SqKm': burnArea.get('area')
    });
print("BA Test", f);

 


Please [Edit] the Question to include the printed value. Partial pixels aren't a thing, but precision issues are.

@Vince Got it, done!

Partial pixels ARE a thing.  The ROI/geometry almost certainly cuts through the middle of some pixels; those values are weighted by the percent of the pixel that's inside the ROI.  If you don't want that, use .unweighted() on the reducer.

@Noel Gorelick thank you! Can you confirm (based on the methods here) that I'm getting pixel area as an output (as opposed to the sum of the 'BurnDate' band values)?
